# Neither do I vs I don't either

Tags: grammar

I have read in several sources that in agreement with a negative statement one can use *either*, for instance:

> I am not a child, and my cousin isn't either.

At the same time, there is the word *neither* that can be used here:

> I am not a child, neither is my cousin.

From the sentences aforementioned, which one sounds more natural? Which is more formal/informal? Is there any difference at all?

Comment: You forgot an *and* in the second sentence.  This is a comma-splice error that will get you marked down in papers, or just looked down upon in general by those who care about such things. But understand that in quick, casual speech, such things aren’t terribly rare either.

Answer (score 2):

> which one sounds more natural

Both are correct, but the second one sounds more natural to me as a British English speaker.

> Which is more formal/informal

Neither sounds particular formal/informal.

> Is there any difference at all?

Not really. Both are valid, grammatical sentences. The second just sounds a little more natural to me.